# Count sum of items using future

Tags: flutter, future

I need to count total items from query from firebase using **Future** and **FutureBuilder** widget

the problem is that the counter keep adding sum.but when i not use setState((){}),the total sum is not updated.

Future Method:

```
  int counter=0;
  Future  get_cart_no() async {
    await FirebaseAuth.instance
        .authStateChanges()
        .listen((User user) {
      if (user != null) {
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('items').where('in_cart',isEqualTo: "yes").where('uid',isEqualTo: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid).get().then((QuerySnapshot snapshot){
          if(snapshot.docs.length > 0){
            int item_q;
            snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
                item_q=doc['item_q'];

               setState((){
                 counter =counter+ item_q;
               });

            });
          }

        });
        print("the total is ${total_items}");
        print("counter is ${counter}");
      };
    });
return counter;
  }
```

FutureBuilder:

```
 FutureBuilder(
                    future: get_cart_no(),
                    builder: (context,snapshot){

                      if(snapshot.connectionState==ConnectionState.done){

                        return Text(counter.toString());
                      }

                      return Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(color: Colors.grey,),
                      );
                    },
                  )
```

**What is the correct way to calculate total sum of that query?**

Comment: have you tried `QuerySnapshot q = await FirebaseFirestore.collection(...).....get(); int counter = q.snapshots().length();`

Comment: This is broken.  Not sure if it's your *only* problem: `future: get_cart_no(),`. Never create the Future for a FutureBuilder as the future: parameter.  Read the first few paragraphs of the FutureBuilder docs for why not, or watch my video on this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sqE-J8YJnpg

Comment: Eray,I need to get sum from a specific row (doc['item_q']) of this query,not the total sum of query itself.

Comment: Randal,I'll watch it.Thank you